# I am a beginner & was trying to create a member procedure and encountered an error - PLS-00538: subprogram or cursor 'REGISTER_FILM' is declared

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE studio_t AS OBJECT
 ( StudioName           VARCHAR2(30),
   StudioAddress        address_t,
   MEMBER PROCEDURE     Reg_Studio(Studio IN OUT NOCOPY studio_t),
   MEMBER PROCEDURE     Register_film(Name_of_Studio IN OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2, films IN OUT NOCOPY film_t) 
   );
/
    
--CREATE STUDIO RECORD MAINTAINING OBJECT TABLE
 
CREATE TABLE Films_table  
    ( Studio    studio_t,
      Filmoch     film_tbl)
        NESTED TABLE Filmoch STORE AS film_tab;
/    
DROP TABLE Films_table;
-- CREATING TYPE BODY OF STUDIO

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY studio_t AS
    MEMBER PROCEDURE Reg_Studio(Studio IN OUT NOCOPY studio_t) 
    IS
     BEGIN 
        
        INSERT INTO Studio_Tab VALUES(Studio);
    END Reg_Studio;
     MEMBER PROCEDURE Register_film(StudioName IN OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2, Films IN OUT NOCOPY film_t) 
    IS
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO Studio_Tab VALUES(StudioName, Films);
    END Register_film;
   END;
 /
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PLS-00539 and PLS-00538 errors when creating UDT functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47047712/pls-00539-and-pls-00538-errors-when-creating-udt-functions)

Comment: The `INSERT` statement in procedure `Reg_Studio` is incorrect. The `INSERT` statement in procedure `Register_film` is also incorrect. I suggest that you check the Oracle documentation for the correct syntax. All the Oracle documentation is available online. Just search for ___oracle database documentation___